# Heteroscedasticity in the regression in computer generated data

Tags: r, predictive-models, residuals

I have a computer generated data and when I plot the raw data, I see the following plot.

[image: Raw data plot. Y is response and X is independent variable]

As a quick and dirty method, I applied linear model to this data and when I plot the predicted vs residual, I got expanding flannel plot which shows that the variance is not random. Therefore, I used `BoxCoxTran` method in `caret` package to transform the input variable. I got this message : `Lambda could not be estimated; no transformation is applied`. The studentized Breusch-Pagan test still shows the p-value to be < 2^-16, which confirms the heteroscedasticity problem in the data.

When I plotted predicted value vs residual, I got flannel shaped scatter plot.
[image: Residual plot]

I tried transforming the idependent variable (taking sqrt, log, second degree polynomial), but nothing helped.

What other methods should I try to create a better classifier?

Edit:
After having clue from the responses below, I created a new variable and then tried to create a model. I finally got relatively better model. The residue plot can be seen below.

```
new_col = Y/(X+0.1)
df$new_col = new_col
model_lm <- lm(Y ~ new_col^2, data = df, na.action=na.exclude)
```

My new question is: For unknown data, how can I get the response?

[image: Residual plot]

Comment: Weighted least squares?

Comment: These data can be handled beautifully with linear models--and probably do not need transformation or weighting.  Plot $y/x$ and proceed from there: that should make it obvious what is going on and it will reveal important details of the smaller variations in the data that are presently obscured.

Comment: This appears to be repeated-measures data. I suggest you look into mixed effects models. In fact, you data looks exactly like what I usually sketch when I explain mixed effects models to our PhD students.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your goals there are different methods that do not assume homoscedasticity. Two such are quantile regression and regression trees.

Comment: The heteroscedasticity in this plot has such an obvious structure that it would be a mistake to work around it.  This is clearly a collection of lines through the origin.  Another way to put it is that there is an extremely strong correlation structure to these data.  Quantile regression will not cope with that.  A regression tree would make short work of it indeed, provided one were to introduce an appropriate variable--namely, one that depends monotonically on $y/x$.

Comment: @whuber, please see my edit. As suggested by you I am able to find relatively good model. For test data (When response is not known), how this model will work? Thanks for your response.